# i could not come up with an answer for this code.Any suggestion?

Tags: python-3.5

```
import numpy as np

n,m,p=map(int,input().strip().split(' '))

arr=[]

arr1=[]

    for i in range(n):

        for j in range(p):

        arr.append(np.array(list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))))
arr=np.array(arr)

    for i in range(m):

        for j in range(p):
        arr1.append(np.array(list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))))
arr1=np.array(arr1)
print(np.concatenate((arr,arr1)),axis=0)
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. What's going on?

Answer (score -1):

Indentation is wrong.
The number of brackets in the last line is wrong.
I've corrected these errors for you:

```
import numpy as np

n,m,p=map(int,input().strip().split(' '))

arr=[]

arr1=[]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(p):
      arr.append(np.array(list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))))
arr=np.array(arr)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(p):
      arr1.append(np.array(list(map(int,input().strip().split(' ')))))
arr1=np.array(arr1)

print(np.concatenate((arr,arr1),axis=0))
```